# ggplot2 adding extra info in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I got a map of Canada

```
library(ggmap)
mp = get_map(location = "Canada", maptype="satellite", color="color")
```

then I want to plot 14 points on the map:

```
p = ggmap(mp) + 
    geom_point(data=GPScor, x=lon, y = lat, col="red", size =2.1) +
```

then i want to number the points on thee graph:

```
geom_text(data=GPScor, aes(x=decLon, y=decLat,label=lbl),
    adj=2,offset=1, color="white", size=4, hjust=4)
```

I can't find the way how to create a legend where it will list the number with the corresponding name of the point:
something like

```
1: "name of point1"
2: "name of point2 "
```

Comment: This question is similar to the one found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202449/add-a-information-in-ggplot-legend-from-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I initially misread the question
You should include the name in an `aes` for your `geom_point`.

```
dat<-data.frame(name=c("a","b","c"), x=1:3, y=1:3)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=paste(1:3,": point",name)))+
  geom_text(aes(x=x,y=y+0.07), label=1:3)+
  labs(shape="locations")
```

If you don't actually want them to be displayed with different shapes, them just override it using 
`scale_shape_manual` and set an arbitrary value.

```
  scale_shape_manual(values=rep(1,3))
```

Below put all together

```
dat<-data.frame(name=c("a","b","c"), x=1:3, y=1:3)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=paste(1:3,": point",name)))+
  geom_text(aes(x=x,y=y+0.07), label=1:3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=rep(1,3))+
  labs(shape="locations")
```

[image]

Here is an example using `ggmap` explicitly

```
mp <- get_map(location = "Canada", maptype="satellite", color="color")
dat<-data.frame(lon=c(-106.6, -106.4), lat=c(56.0, 56.2), names=c("1","2"))
  ggmap(mp)+
  geom_point(data=dat, aes(x=lon, y = lat, 
             color=paste(seq_along(dat$lon), ": location", names),
             shape=paste(seq_along(dat$lon), ": location", names)))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=rep(1,nrow(dat)))+
  labs(shape="locations", color="locations")
```

Comment: just take the relevant `geom_point` portion and add as you would otherwise

Comment: you seem to use `geom_point` fine above no? Or was your question about having errors with `geom__point` as well?

Comment: library(ggmap)
    mp = get_map(location = "Canada", maptype="satellite", color="color")
    dat<-data.frame(name=c("a","b","c"), x=1:3, y=1:3)
    p = ggmap(mp) + geom_point(dat, aes(x=x, y=y,shape=paste(1:3,": point",name)))+
    geom_text(aes(x=x,y=y+0.07), label=1:3)+
    scale_shape_manual(values=rep(1,3))+
    labs(shape="locations")

in geom_point I get an error that "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: you can't just add this to your example. My trivial example above is just to show how aes(shape) should be used, you need to adapt this for your example as needed....

Comment: Gotcha. Will download ggmap on my computer and send a solution. I was at work, so couldn't do that before

Comment: added `ggmap` example