# Add a information in ggplot legend from data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I want to add information in legend which sensor has this value.

Here is my code:

```
z <- data.frame(
       a=c("sensor 1","sensor 2","sensor 3","sensor 4","sensor 5","sensor 6","sensor 7","sensor 8"), 
       b=c(50, 60, 70, 20,90,110,30,100)
     )

cxc <- ggplot(z, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=factor(b))) + 
         geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity",colour = "black")  + 
         scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues",type = "seq")+
         geom_text(aes(y = b/2,label = b),color = "red",size = 5)
cxc + coord_polar() + 
  theme_linedraw() + 
  theme(axis.ticks =element_blank(), axis.text.y =element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(size = 12,angle = 45)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Value and sensor"))
```

Here is my result:
[image]

I want in legend write like this:

- 20 (sensor 4)
- 30 (sensor 7)
- 50 (sensor 1)

I want keep this colors and graph style.

Comment: You could use the `labels` argument to `scale_fill_brewer`

Comment: @RichardTelford Yes but problem is when I put `scale_fill_brewer(labels = z$a)` I got text, but not right text for value. I don't know how can put right sensor for value without hand writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `labels` argument to `scale_fill_brewer`, and `order` the labels so they come in the correct order.

```
cxc <- ggplot(z, aes(x=a, y=b, fill=factor(b))) + 
  geom_bar(width = 1,stat="identity",colour = "black")  + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues",type = "seq", labels = paste0(z$b, " (", z$a, ")")[order(z$b)])+
  geom_text(aes(y = b/2,label = b),color = "red",size = 5)
cxc + coord_polar() + 
  theme_linedraw() + 
  theme(axis.ticks =element_blank(), axis.text.y =element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(size = 12,angle = 45)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Value and sensor"))
```